# Initialize dataframe with two columns which have one of the them all zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list and I would like to convert it to a pandas dataframe. In the second column, I want to give all zeros but I got "object of type 'int' has no len()" error. The thing I did is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([all_equal_timestamps['A'], 0],  columns=['data','label'])
```

How can i add second column with all zeros to this dataframe in the easiest manner and why did the code above give me this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is in `all_equal_timestamps`, so I presume it's a list of elements. Do you mean to get this result?

```
import pandas as pd

all_equal_timestamps = {'A': ['1234', 'aaa', 'asdf']}
df = pd.DataFrame(all_equal_timestamps['A'],  columns=['data']).assign(label=0)
# df['label'] = 0
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   data  label
0  1234      0
1   aaa      0
2  asdf      0
```

If you're creating a DataFrame with a list of lists, you'd expect something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ all_equal_timestamps['A'], '0'*len(all_equal_timestamps['A']) ],  columns=['data', 'label', 'anothercol'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   data label anothercol
0  1234   aaa       asdf
1     0     0          0
```

Comment: I wrote it in the first answer as a comment. But isn't there a cleaner way? why do i need extra line just for this?

Comment: I see, if you want it in 1 line, the best way is to use `.assign()` as suggested by @MichaelS.. I've edited my answer above

Answer (score 1):

you can add a column named as "new" with all zero by using

```
df['new'] = 0
```

Comment: But why do I need extra line just for this simple task

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in one line with `assign`:

```py
timestamps = [1,0,3,5]

pd.DataFrame({"Data":timestamps}).assign(new=0)
```

Output:

```
   Data new
0   1   0
1   0   0
2   3   0
3   5   0
```